# Shutdown of IHostedService

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core, console-application

I am trying to develop an asynchronous, multi-threaded .NET Core console app, but after implementing the code from the tutorial once starts to implement this, the code is shut down

> Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: application is shutting down

Started to write a method to execute using asynchronous, multi-threaded

```
private async Task<List<RegistrationData>> ProcessPendingRegistrationsAsync(List<RegistrationData>  registrations)
{
    return registrations;
}
```

and then I run this method using "Task.Run"

```
foreach (var openPendingRegistrationsData in openPendingRegistrationsPerPages)
    processPendingRegistrationsTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => ProcessPendingRegistrationsAsync(openPendingRegistrationsData)
);
```

and finally, I want to await all tasks using `await Task.WhenAll()`:

```
if (processPendingRegistrationsTasks.Count > 0)
{
    await Task.WhenAll(processPendingRegistrationsTasks);
}

Console.WriteLine("Finish running code");
```

To more clear the code didn't print the message in `Console.WriteLine`, once I implement `Task.WhenAll`.

Please, can anyone let me know what the problem is?

**EDIT**

Program.cs

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var log4NetConfiguration = new Log4NetConfiguration();
        log4NetConfiguration.SetLog4NetConfiguration();
        var host = CreateHostDefaultBuilder(args).Build();
        host.RunAsync();
        RunTask(host.Services);
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostDefaultBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(app => { app.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json"); })
            .ConfigureServices((_, services) =>
            {
                services.ConfigureDAL().ConfigureBusiness().ConfigureConnectionHelper().ConfigureTimeOutSetting();
            });
    }

    public static void RunTask(IServiceProvider services)
    {
        var taskHelper = (TaskHelper)services.GetService(typeof(TaskHelper));
        taskHelper?.Execute(true);
    }
}
```

TaskHelper.cs

```
public async Task Execute(bool forceMode)
{
    var openPendingRegistrationsPerPages =
            _dRegistration.GetAllRegistrationsByStatusAndSubStatusPerPage(cachedByGuid[1], cachedByGuid[2]);

    foreach (var openPendingRegistrationsData in openPendingRegistrationsPerPages)
        processPendingRegistrationsTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => ProcessPendingRegistrationsAsync(openPendingRegistrationsData));
}

if (processPendingRegistrationsTasks.Count > 0)
{
    await Task.WhenAll(processPendingRegistrationsTasks);
}

Console.WriteLine("Finish running code");


private async Task<List<RegistrationData>> ProcessPendingRegistrationsAsync(List<RegistrationData>  registrations)
{
    // Process
    return registrations;
}
```

Comment: @mohammadhamid Can you please share all of your code? Minimum code, but all of it

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary ,I added some codes, I hope it's useful

Comment: Thanks, what is the return type of `GetAllRegistrationsByStatusAndSubStatusPerPage`?

Comment: Also - where are you registering `TaskHelper` for dependency injection?

Comment: Mohammad, try `taskHelper?.Execute(true).Result;` as you're not waiting for the `Task` to finish which may cause the `HostedService` to shut down before your processing is complete - does that work?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary GetAllRegistrationsByStatusAndSubStatusPerPage, is return List<List<RegistrationData> ,

Comment: You can see ConfigureDAL in the program.cs in method CreateHostDefaultBuilder, in this I do DI

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary , I can't add Result  after taskHelper?.Execute(true).

Comment: Why not? Then how are you meant to wait for the tasks to finish?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, I mean I can't find option Result,

Comment: Sorry, I read `Task<T>` which is wrong - try `Task.Run(() => taskHelper?.Execute(true)).Wait();`

Comment: I don't know hh, but I added taskHelper?.Execute(true).wait() , and its work without Task.Run, are its save or ur way is best

Comment: Just do `taskHelper?.Execute(true).wait()` - does that fix your problem? Is the code working? There's not a notable difference in this case

Comment: Yes, it works the same like Task.Run(() => taskHelper?.Execute(true)).Wait(); , works

Comment: Okay perfect - I will post an answer in a sec so that comments are not lost and so others may find it useful - you're welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You're not waiting for `taskHelper.Execute(true)` to finish executing.**

The issue stems from your `RunTask(...)` method:

```
public static void RunTask(IServiceProvider services)
{
  var taskHelper = (TaskHelper)services.GetService(typeof(TaskHelper));
  taskHelper?.Execute(true);
}
```

`.Execute` returns a `Task`:

```
public async Task Execute(bool forceMode)
```

Unless you `await` this call which you can't since `RunTask` is not an `async` method, your code will not wait for the `Task` returned by the method to finish running.

In this case, the simple solution would be to **use the [`Task.Wait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait?view=net-5.0) method to wait for the Task to complete execution**.

This should work:

```
public static void RunTask(IServiceProvider services)
{
  var taskHelper = (TaskHelper)services.GetService(typeof(TaskHelper));
  taskHelper?.Execute(true).Wait();
}
```